# Question about AWS greengrass edge computaiton on raspberry model 3

Tags: java, aws-iot, aws-lambda-edge, aws-iot-greengrass

I want to set up edge computaiton environment with raspberry model 3, according to AWS IOT Greengrass development guidence. When it comes to deployment of "helloworld" lambda function on the board, a stange problem occured, the status is always "in progress" and no any feedback is given.
I tried several times to make sure each operation correct, but the same problem still is there.

Please help give some suggestions how to find out the reason and resolve it.
many thanks

Comment: Can you confirm what language your "helloworld" lambda function is written in please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolve these issues:

1. Check that the Greengrass daemon is running on the device. `sudo systemctl start greengrass`.
2. On the PI run the `top` command before you start the deployment. As the deployment starts you should start to see python processes consuming more CPU. If you don't see this then your deployment isn't actually starting on the device.
3. Examine the log files in `/greengrass/ggc/var/log` to check for any errors. There are both `user` and `system` logs. In the system logs you should see some evidence that something happened. That is, one of the files should have been updated around the time you started your deployment. You can then `tail` this file to see if there have been any errors.

I would suggest this as a starting point. If we can see evidence that the deployment started and potentially an error in one of those logs it will be possible to investigate further.